# As3 Communicate with C# or Asp.net

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, url, post, get

I have been looking around for hours trying to find a clear simple solution to my question and have yet to find a good answer. I am trying to do a URL request in flash to my NOPCommerce site. I want to pass a GET value to the my .cs file which i'll then use that value to grab specific information and return it back to flash. How would I set up the C# or asp.net side of things? If anyone could give me an example of what I am looking for I would greatly appreciate it.

I don't know if I am supposed to use a .aspx, .cs or .ascx file.

Thanks,
Brennan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it to be extremely simple with web services in as3. Here is a link to see what I mean

[As3 Web Services](http://labs.alducente.com/gophr/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the HttpWebRequest class to GET the variables, do the magic and return a result by invoking the HttpWebRequest again.

Examples and usage here:
http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options for server-side communication with flash.

1. Flash remoting. This is the most popular because it's the most performant, but not the easiest to understand at first glance. It transfers data in a binary format. Available libraries are Weborb and Fluorine.
2. Web Services as mentioned in a previous post.
3. Ajax/JSON. I think with Flash Player 11.3, JSON decoding is native in the player now.
4. Straight up http request.
5. Sockets (not recommended for beginners)

To answer your question as you asked it, though, for all but #4, you'd be using a CS file to retrieve your data. For #4, you'd most likely be using an .aspx page, but it could be a combination of .aspx and .ascx files.

My recommendation is that you do some research on each of these methods to decide what would work best with your development environment, required level of security, and project. Then, ask specific questions about each method as necessary.

Good Luck!